# Como saber quando Collapsible se expande ou fecha?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Tenho um [collapsible](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsible/), e quando ele for expandido quero acrescentar elementos nele, e quando for recolhido quero excluir os elementos.

 No momento estou usando da seguinte forma:

```
<div id="expansorTurma" data-role="collapsible">
    <h4 id="expansorTurmaTitle" onclick="montarCursos()">Não sei o código da minha turma.</h4>
    <h6>Escolha seu curso.</h6>

    <div id="cursos"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function montarCursos() {
         /** **/
        $("#cursos").append(<button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Elemento</button>')
        /** **/
    }
</script>
```

Mas neste caso encontro um grande problema, pois cada vez que o botão é clicado um novo elemento é criado, mas preciso que ele seja criado apenas uma vez, e depois excluído.

Comment: Quando o elemento está fechado ele possui a classe `ui-collapsible-collapsed`, quando aberto essa classe é removida. Pra saber quando ele está aberto ou não, basta ver se a classe mencionada anteriormente está presente.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou perfeitamente! Poderia postar como resposta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a descrição da api
https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-collapse

Você pode "escutar" estes eventos:

```
$( "#expansorTurma" )
   .on( "collapsiblecollapse", function( event, ui ) {
         $("#cursos").html("");
    } )
   .on( "collapsibleexpand", function( event, ui ) {
         $("#cursos").append('<button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Elemento</button>');
    } );
```